# Match character group only if not at the end of the string

Tags: regex

I've got this regex `/^!balance ([^\s]+ ){3}/i`. Basically the string should start with `!balance`, a space, and then exactly 3 words each separated with exactly one space. This, works but requires the string to also have one space at the end of the string.

`!balance whatever whatever whatever ---> matches, but requires space after the last 'whatever'`.

What should I add so that it matches without a space at the end?

Comment: `/^!balance ([^\s]+ |$){3}/i` what if you or it with end of line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just turn the regex around, /^!balance( [^\s]+){3}/i to require a space at the beginning of the word. This will cover the space after balance by moving the space into the match group.

Comment: Or a bit shorter  `/^!balance( \S+){3}/i`